# Grok parser: How to parse log message

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Log message:

```
2019-06-04 20:29:19,164 level=[ERROR] app=__main__:  Raised Exception: Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Gork parser:
I am trying to parse above log message to get log_status(ERROR)
but I am not able to match the gork pattern.

I am using:

```
rule %{date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):date} %{number:test} level=\[%{word:log_status}\]
```

but i get invalid pattern,

Answer (score 0):

rule %{date("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"):date}%{regex("[,]*"):comm}%{word:test} level=[%{word:texttt}].*